# How to put span in Jade?

Tags: html, css, pug

I searched through the web, but I didn't find the answer of my question.
How can I put a span tag inside p tag with the help of Jade template language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
p
    | Text before span
    span Text in span
    | Text after span
```

Just basic Jade nesting and text...